# How to set different ENV variable when building and deploying Docker Image to Cloud Run?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gcloud, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I have a backend service that I'll need to deploy to `Google Cloud Run`.

From [Google's tutorial on Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy#node.js), we get that:

First you need to build your image and send it to **Cloud Build**.

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/helloworld
```

Only then you deploy it to Cloud Run:

```
gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/helloworld --platform managed
```

I get the sequence above. But I'll be deploying this service to 2 different environments: `TEST` and `PROD`.

So I need an `SERVER_ENV` variable, that should be `"PROD"` on my production environment, and of course it should be `"TEST"` on my test environment. This is so my server (express server that will be run from the container) knows which database to connect to.

But the problem is that I only have a single `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:12-slim

ENV SERVER_ENV=PROD

WORKDIR /

COPY ./package.json ./package.json
COPY ./distApp ./distApp
COPY ./distService ./distService
COPY ./public ./public

RUN npm install

ENTRYPOINT npm start
```

So how can I set different `ENV` variables while following the build & deploy sequence above? Is there an option in the `gcloud builds submit` comment that I can maybe override something? Or use a different `Dockerfile`? Anybody got other ideas?

**AN IDEA:**

Maybe use the [Cloud Build configuration file](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config)?

`cloudbuild.yaml`

Comment: i think that what you are trying to achieve is possible using build args : https://vsupalov.com/docker-env-vars/. if it works ill submit a regular answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't achieve this without a `cloudbuild.yaml` file. The command `gcloud builds submit --tag ...` doesn't accept extra docker parameter.

Here an example of configuration

```
FROM node:12-slim

ARG SERVER_CONF=PROD
ENV SERVER_ENV=$SERVER_CONF

WORKDIR /

COPY ./package.json ./package.json
COPY ./distApp ./distApp
COPY ./distService ./distService
COPY ./public ./public

RUN npm install

ENTRYPOINT npm start
```

*I created a build argument `SERVER_CONF`. Your `ENV` will take this value at build time. The default value is `PROD`*

Now your `cloudbuild.yaml` file

```
step:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['build', '--tag=gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/helloworld', '--build-arg="SERVER_CONF=$_SERVER_CONF"', '.']
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['push', 'gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/helloworld']
substitutions:
  _SERVER_CONFPROD: PROD
```

*Use substitution variables to change the environment. Not that here you can also set a default value, that override your Dockerfile value. Take care of this!*

*You can also set the tag as substitution variable if you want*

Eventually, how to call your Cloud Build

```
# With default server conf (no substitution variables, the the file default)
gcloud builds submit

# With defined server conf
gcloud builds submit --substitutions=_SERVER_CONF=TEST
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it really not possible to do it using only the `gcloud` CLI? I guess I'll have to dive a little deeper into the Cloud Build docs. Do you think it's possible to build image locally and deploy it straight to Cloud Run? Like bypassing the Cloud Build step.

Comment: Yep, you can build locally but you need to push the image at the end `docker build --tag=gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/helloworld --build-arg=SERVER_CONF=TEST . && docker push gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/helloworld`

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are trying to achieve is possible using the `ARG` instruction in the Dockerfile.

I would set it to be `test` and then use the arg parameter according to the environment you are building in right now.

More docs:

- how to use it with Docker Compose - https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args
- additional documentation - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact