# Is there a way to inspect the process.env variables on a cloud run service?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, environment-variables, google-cloud-run

After deployment, is there a way to inspect the `process.env` variables on a running cloud run service?

I thought they would be available in the following page:

https://console.cloud.google.com/run/detail

[image]

Is there a way to make them available here? Or to inspect it in some other way?

**PS:** This is a Docker container.

I have the following `ENV` on my Dockerfile. And I know they are present, because everything is working as it should. But I cannot see them in the service details:

**Dockerfile**

```
ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV PROJECT_ID=$PROJECT_ID
ENV SERVER_ENV=$SERVER_ENV
```

I'm using a `cloudbuild.yaml` file. The `ENV` directives are present in my `Dockerfile`, and they are being passed to my container. Maybe I should add `env` to my `cloudbuild.yaml` file? Because I'm using `--substitutions` on my `gcloub builds sumbmit` call and they are passed as `--build-arg` to my `Docker build` step. But I'm not declaring them as `env` in my `cloudbuild.yaml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/environment-variables#console) and set the environment variables on a Cloud Run service using the console.Then I was able to list them on the Google Cloud Console.

> You can set environment variables using the Cloud Console, the gcloud
> command line, or a YAML file when you create a new service or deploy a
> new revision:

Comment: I'm using a `cloudbuild.yaml` file. The `ENV` directives are present in my `Dockerfile`, and they are being passed to my container. I've updated the question. Maybe I should add `env` to my `cloudbuild.yaml` file? Because I'm using `substitutions` to pass them as `--build-arg` to my `Docker build` step. But I'm not declaring them as `env` in my `cloudbuild.yaml`. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, you should add the env variable to `cloudbuild.yaml`  file [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65204287/how-to-set-different-env-variable-when-building-and-deploying-docker-image-to-cl)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @marian.vladoi's answer. This what I've ended up doing

In my deploy step from `cloudbuild.yaml` file:

I added the `--set-env-vars` parameter

```
steps:

    # DEPLOY CONTAINER WITH GCLOUD
  - name: "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk"
    entrypoint: gcloud
    args:
      - "beta"
      - "run"
      - "deploy"
      - "SERVICE_NAME"
      - "--image=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/SERVICE_NAME:$_TAG_NAME"
      - "--platform=managed"
      - "--region=us-central1"
      - "--min-instances=$_MIN_INSTANCES"
      - "--max-instances=3"
      - "--set-env-vars=PROJECT_ID=$PROJECT_ID,SERVER_ENV=$_SERVER_ENV,NODE_ENV=production"
      - "--port=8080"
      - "--allow-unauthenticated"
    timeout: 180s
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
printenv
```

or

```
printenv -0
```

It will help you to figure out which evn variables already present in your space.